# How to prevent Material Design Web Drawer from closing by swipe?

Tags: javascript, material-design, swipe, material-components

I have Material design drawer, how can I remove events like `touchmove`, `touchstart` and `touchend` which close my drawer if I swipe to left?

Comment: Why not try [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)?

Comment: @benvc I have inside my sidebar some items which need touch events - like price slider, color wheel...

but I tried also to ```preventDefault```, ```stopPropagation```... it seems that in library it already event which fires up... and if I haven'n point to this function I cant to ```removeEventListener()``` ...

Anyway thanks for the comment

Comment: Depending on the component you are using, some have a "permanent" or "fixed" option built in if you want the drawer to be a fixed navigation element that never closes. That said, I am not exactly sure what you are after. If you post the relevant part of your code with a bit more explanation of what you want, someone may be able to help out more.

Comment: @benvc great, I want that in desktop it should be permanent, but in mobile it should be 'closable'. this is the demo... http://mature-caption.surge.sh/

Comment: in mobile.. like if you want to choose sorting options(which are offscreen)

or something else, sometimes it closes menu